# The annihilator of a primary submodule is a primary ideal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $M$ be a finitely generated module over a commutative Noetherian ring, $R$. Prove that if $N \subset M$ is a $\mathfrak{p} -$primary sub-module, then $A \colon =$ Ann$_R(M/N) $ is a primary sub-module of $R$.

As part of a build up, I have shown there is an equivalent condition to being a primary submodule:

$N\subset M$ is a primary submodule if and only if $rm \in N $ for some $r\in R$ and $m\in M\setminus N$ implies $r^km \in N $ for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.

With this in mind, is it best to show that if $rs \in A$ for some $r\in R$ and $s\in R\setminus A$ then $r^kR \subset A $?

Otherwise, should we somehow show that the associated primes of $R/A $ are associated primes of $M/N$?

Perhaps we can show $A$ is irreducible (as a result of $N$ being $\mathfrak{p}-$primary)?

Any suggestions would help greatly. Thank you.